# Keep the result of a correlated sub-query

Tags: mysql

Imagine I have a query like this:

```
Select 
  (SELECT a FROM table_10 LIMIT 1) AS sb1,
  (SELECT a FROM table_11 WHERE a=sb1 LIMIT 1) AS sb2,
  (SELECT a FROM table_12 WHERE a=sb2 LIMIT 1) AS sb3
FROM my_table WHERE 1
```

I far as I found out the values for sb1,sb2 and sb3 are not saved in the memory and when the second sub-query refers to sb1 it re-runs the first sub-query again. when the third sub-query refers to sb2, the second sub-query re-runs thus the first one will re-run many times.
My reason for this is when I hard code the result instead of referring to the result of sb1 and sb2 I see a very huge difference in query time. (Like 30 seconds!)

My first question: Am I right?
My second question: How can I force mysql to keep the value in sb1 and sb2 and not to run the query each time?
My third question: If I'm not right, then what is causing this difference in time and performance?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I force mysql to keep the value in sb1 and sb2 and not to run the query each time?

Convert your correlated queries to JOIN. Formally (ignoring ambiguities) it will be

```
Select 
  table_10.a AS sb1,
  table_11.a AS sb2,
  table_12.a AS sb3
FROM my_table 
CROSS JOIN table_10
INNER JOIN table_11 ON a=sb1
INNER JOIN table_12 ON a=sb2
WHERE 1
LIMIT 1
```

PS. LIMIT without ORDER BY makes no sense. Both in original code and provided one.

PPS. Specify table alias for EACH column name.